# How to remove a Google Apps email alias on an alias domain?

Tags: google-workspace, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

We're using Google Apps (or Gsuite, as it's called now) to manage Gmail emails on our own domain name; let's call it `domain.com`. We're also using a domain alias, let's call it `alias.com`.

I have just suspended a user, `john`, and I want to forward his email to another account. As suggested [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/rNlsNpjuOPg), I have:

- renamed the `john` account to `john.suspended`
- removed the automatic alias `john@domain.com` from `john.suspended`
- added `john@domain.com` as an alias for the user I want to forward the email to

While it seems to work for `john@domain.com`, it doesn't work for `john@alias.com`, I receive a non-deliverable notification because "the user is suspended".

When I look at the `john` account, there are indeed 2 aliases left:

- `john@alias.com`
- `john.suspended@alias.com`

But I cannot remove these aliases: they don't have the "remove" link next to them.

I don't care about the latter, but `john@alias.com` is a big issue: this is precisely the email I wanted to redirect.

**How can I remove the email alias `john@alias.com` from the `john` account?**

Answer (score 1):

When using a [domain alias](https://support.google.com/a/answer/182079?hl=en), every account in your domain gets the other address at the alias domain. You can't change or remove this for a single account.

To address your direct question, you can not remove john@alias.com from the account john@domain.com. If you have renamed the account to john.suspended@domain.com, rather than adding john.suspended@domain.com as another alias, then john@alias.com should either no longer be an alias on that account, or you should be able to remove it.

If you can't, I recommend contacting Google Support as it appears this is bugged.